# Forward users to the right template according to the current active site's language

Tags: craft2

I am using Craft 2 and trying to forward users to the right template according to the current active site's language when they reset their password. The problem is that the reset URL that Craft creates and sends the user's email only forwards it to the primary site.

To be more clear, if the user changed site language to Germany and sends for a reset password request, the URL sent to his email sends him to the primary site, which is the French  one.

I added the setPasswordPath in the config file as such:

```
'setPasswordPath' => array(
    'de' => 'de/passwordreset'
    'fr' => 'passwordreset',
),
```

But still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a good solution for this in Craft 2 without some custom plugin logic.

To be fair, this was the same behavior in Craft 3 until [pretty recently](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3029) as well.

You might want to comment on that Github issue to see about the feasibility of backporting something to Craft 2 for this.